# pyinstaller command could not be found

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert my python script into an exe using

`pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py`

But I get the following error:

`the command "pyinstaller" is either misspelled or could not be found.`

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed it, find the location, and add the folder path to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: If you haven't installed it, running `pip3 install pyinstaller` will take of that

Comment: i do have it installed but whats the location of my path environment variable?

Comment: You need to find your Python installation and Pyinstaller will likely be somewhere around there.  Only you can figure out your installation location.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not installed. Try

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

and that will tell you if it is installed or will install it. If it says you do not have privileges, you may have to do

```
sudo pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: it is installed, pip show pyinstaller works!

Comment: If you don't remember where it is located, running the install again should show you. Once you know where, you need to run it from that directory. It will be easiest if the "myfile.py" is in the same directory.